# Spring Boot File Upload - Connection reset by peer error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am doing file upload with Spring Boot and I am getting the following error.

```
Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Connection reset by peer
```

I searched for this error and found [this article](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-file-upload-and-connection-reset-issue/) which says this error occurs when user tries to upload a file which is larger than the specified limit.

But for my application this scenario is not possible because I check the file size in the UI code before uploading the file.

Here is my file upload controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "fileUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFile(@RequestParam("uploadedFile") MultipartFile uploadedFile,
                                    PersistentEntityResourceAssembler resourceAssembler) throws IOException {

    if (uploadedFile.getSize() / 1024 > MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
        throw new CustomConstraintViolationException("File Size exceeds 25 MB");
    }

    //save file

    return new ResponseEntity<>(resourceAssembler.toResource(savedFile), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

I also have file size specified in the application.properties as well.

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=26240KB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=26240KB
```

So what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.17

**UPDATE 2**

Here is the full stacktrace

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Connection reset by peer at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:116) at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:90) at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:81) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1104) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:936) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.java:53) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.java:82) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:84) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:206) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.java:79) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.java:82) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:206) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:240) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:84) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractAuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke(AbstractAuthenticatedActionsValve.java:67) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.invoke(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:181) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Connection reset by peer at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2950) at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3242) at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1136) at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:381) at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:84) ... 29 more Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Connection reset by peer at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:297) at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2902) ... 33 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method) at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39) at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223) at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197) at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.read(NioChannel.java:147) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.read(NioBlockingSelector.java:173) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:235) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:216) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1280) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1223) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:729) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.access$300(Http11InputBuffer.java:40) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:1084) at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:140) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:263) at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:581) at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:326) at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.checkByteBufferEof(InputBuffer.java:642) at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:349) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:183) at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133) at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:132) at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:977) at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:881) at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133) at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:132) at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107) at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:98) at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:68) at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:293) ... 34 more
```

Comment: Please specify what Spring boot version are you using ?

Comment: Are you able to check what class exactly is throwing this `IOFileUploadException`? Looks like it's not coming from `uploadFile` method, right?

Comment: can you show your `POST` request? I mean from where you upload file, html/ajax request file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem, I found out this error was caused by a timeout set on file uploads by UI and it is not related to Spring. Now this may not be true for all instances of this error so take a look  at [this article](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-file-upload-and-connection-reset-issue/) as well.

Comment: This is not a good solution. BEcause you're basically allowing any amount of data, which can end up creating a DOS attack. The solution is to be able to configure the server to forward that error to any handlers that have been set.

Comment: I think you're mistaken. The article I linked for exactly specifying the file size limit in the backend server

Comment: I'm not mistaken. There is max file size, max request size, and max swallow size. Max file size is maximum allowed size for file uploads. Max request size is max allowed request body size. Max swallow size is how many bytes Tomcat will ingest (into the void) until it returns an error when a file upload request exceeds the maxFileSize property, to allow browsers to properly receive an HTTP response instead of terminating the connection. If you specify an unlimited maxSwallow size, the server will keep "swallowing" the data in order to get to end of it and properly return an HTTP...

Comment: ...response code, otherwise the connection gets terminated without sending any headers. So, it's a Denial of Service attack vector. Unless you specify maxSwallow to be the same as maxFileSize. So again, the design should have been to return a 413 instead of terminating the request.

Comment: I am not sure where I have mentioned to set an unlimited `maxSwallowSize`

Answer (score 4):

You can check the following `application.properties` whether configured correctly related to `multipart` [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

## MULTIPART (MultipartProperties)

```
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true # Whether to enable support of multipart uploads.
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=0B # Threshold after which files are written to disk.
spring.servlet.multipart.location= # Intermediate location of uploaded files.
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=1MB # Max file size.
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB # Max request size.
spring.servlet.multipart.resolve-lazily=false # Whether to resolve the multipart request lazily at the time of file or parameter access.
```

The error(resolved) as stated by asker is (Just quoting his comment)

> I checked the axios request in UI and it turns out there is a 5 minute
>   timeout set on file upload. So the request gets cancelled if it takes
>   more than 5 minutes and that's causing the connection reset issue.

Comment: I havent set any multipart properties apart from the ones mentioned in the question. Would that cause a problem?

Comment: Ideally not. You can try mentioning the size in MB. Since in docs, it is always given in MB. Also, it would be helpful to see your POST request

Comment: Hey I figured it out. I checked the axios request in UI and it turns out there is a 5 minute timeout set on file upload. So the request gets cancelled if it takes more than 5 minutes and that's causing the connection reset issue.

Answer (score 1):

Put below given configuration in properties file

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=25MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=25MB
```

Instestead of

`spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=26240KB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=26240KB`

It Should solve your problem.

Comment: When I try to upload a file size larger than 25mb it gives me the appropriate error message. So the property part is not the actual issue

Comment: @DeltaCharlie whatever maximum size you want allow configure that in properties file and it will work fine.

Comment: The issue is about timeout. The file size being too big is actually shown in the stack trace reason. But the issue is that the exception cannot be handled because the connection gets reset before the request completes. Your asnwer does not solve anythgin